# prevent other www pages redirecting to homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess

So my main goals are:

- http -> https
- www -> non-www
- remove index.php from urls

After accomplishing the above, the problem I'm having is pages like https://www.disposable.network/api redirect to https://disposable.network instead of redirecting to https://disposable.network/api

**/public_html/disposable.network/.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php81” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php81 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

**/public_html/disposable.network/*public*/.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #start: code from script
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    #end: code from script

    # Redirect http to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]

    # Redirect non-www to www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://disposable\.network/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

    #remove index.php from url
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
</IfModule>
```

**File structure:**

```
|(ROOT: public_html/disposable.network/) [.htaccess]
|-app
|---Actions
|---Console
|---Exceptions
|---Http
|---Mail
|---Models
|---Providers
|---Services
|---View
|-bootstrap
|---cache
|-config
|-database
|---factories
|---migrations
|---seeders
|-public [.htaccess] [sitemap.xml] [index.php]
|---assets
|---attachments
|---css
|---images
|---imgs
|---js
|---livewire
|---tmp
|---vendor
|-resources
|---css
|---js
|---lang
|---views
|-routes
|-storage
|---app
|---framework
|---logs
|-tests
|---Feature
|---Unit
|-vendor
|---asm89
|---bacon
|---bin
|---brick
|---composer
|---dasprid
|---ddeboer
|---dflydev
|---doctrine
|---dragonmantank
|---egulias
|---facade
|---fideloper
|---filp
|---fruitcake
|---fzaninotto
|---graham-campbell
|---guzzlehttp
|---hamcrest
|---jaybizzle
|---jenssegers
|---laravel
|---league
|---livewire
|---mobiledetect
|---mockery
|---monolog
|---myclabs
|---nesbot
|---nette
|---nikic
|---nunomaduro
|---opis
|---paragonie
|---phar-io
|---phpoption
|---phpunit
|---pragmarx
|---psr
|---psy
|---ralouphie
|---ramsey
|---sebastian
|---swiftmailer
|---symfony
|---theseer
|---tijsverkoyen
|---vlucas
|---voku
|---webmozart
```

*Is **/api** a virtual url?* I'm not familiar with that terminology, but I believe so since I created it from the backend of the site.

Comment: In which directory is the `.htaccess` file? Are you implementing HSTS?

Comment: @MrWhite I am not implementing HSTS, as I haven't figured out how to do that yet. Initial .htaccess is in /public_html/disposable.network that serves files and utilizes second .htaccess (code above) in /public_html/disposable.network/public

Comment: (Whether you are (planning to) implement HSTS affects the order of the canonical redirects.) If I'm understanding correctly... the `.htaccess` file you've posted is in a `/public` subdirectory, which is not present in the visible URL... but if that's the case then there shouldn't (need to be) be any canonical redirects in this `.htaccess` file in the first place?! What is `/api` in your question - just a virtual URL? What is your document root? `/public_html` or `/public_html/disposable.network`? Please include your file structure in your Q and _both_ `.htaccess` files.

Comment: ...an issue with the rules you have posted is that 2 of the canonical redirects (above) _assume_ the `.htaccess` file in question is located in the document root - but from your comment, that does not seem to be the case. (?)

Comment: @MrWhite I've included what you've asked for in the edits. thank you for the continued help. Just to clarify, when you say canonical redirect, are those the rules that don't include the R=301?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> # Redirect http to https
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
> RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
>
> # Redirect non-www to www
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule (.*) https://disposable\.network/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
>
> #remove index.php from url
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
> RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
> ```

Your rules are in the wrong order. Your canonical redirects need to be *before* your "front-controller pattern" (rewrite to `index.php`).

Since you are hardcoding the hostname in the second rule, the second *condition* on that rule is superfluous.

Comment: Still can't get it to work properly. I threw the revised in the html field of a codepen so you can see: https://codepen.io/Connor-Perzely/pen/ExMXqZq